# How to insert a column in hive table by taking unique values from 5 different column in another hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hive table with the below schema.

Table A:

```
li_number string
id1 string
id2 string
id3 string
id4 string
id5 string
id6 string
id7 string
id8 string
id9 string
id10 string
created_date date
```

Table B:

```
id string
created_date date
```

From table A, I need to take unique id's from `id1` to `id10` and load them in table B `id` column. Also I need to load created date column with the current date of loading.

I have achieved the same using an shell script and load statement of hive, but I need this to be done using only hive.

Comment: any help for the above issue....

Comment: I've voted to migrate to StackOverflow. There are 7 questions tagged with `apache-hive` here on U/L, and 15,249 questions tagged with `hive` on StackOverflow.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this issue...